# (Python) list extend efficiency

Tags: python, list

Here is some code that I wrote using Python,
got error `form extend_list(3) == [3]`

I know that because the empty list already in the function
so that incoming parameters list `extend_list(2,[])` can get `[2]`
`extend_list(3)` get `[1,3]`

```
def extend_list(val, l=[]):
    l.append(val)
    return l

def test_extend_list():
    # 1
    assert extend_list(1) == [1]
    # 2
    assert extend_list(2, []) == [2]
    # 3
    assert extend_list(3) == [3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_extend_list()
```

==================================================
after modified as following :

```
def extend_list(val, l=[]):
    # l = []
    l.append(val)
    return [l[-1]]

def test_extend_list():
    # 1
    assert extend_list(1) == [1]
    # 2
    assert extend_list(2, []) == [2]
    # 3
    assert extend_list(3) == [3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_extend_list()
```

My problem is,

if that approach is good for python characteristic?
of have another way to have more efficient?

Comment: And you are using mutatable default parameter. That's the reason you got `[1,3]`.

Comment: Yes, you rigft, I mean that problem I can fix, but have another way to solve this problem in more efficient than my method?